# How to make " for a in range (n) loop " and calls out data[a+1]

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm encountering a problem where I need to use for a in range (n) loop to solve things out. But there's a condition where sometimes I might need to call out index[a+1] to satisfy if-conditions. I realize this would result in index out of range error, is there any solution to this or should I implement another method ? Some codes attached.

```
for c in range (n):
  out=enter+width[c]
  if power==cap:
         power-=(width[c])*(height[c])*2+2+enter
  elif power<cap:
         power-=(width[c])*(height[c])*2
  print("Field {:d}: completed. Battery: {:d}.".format(c+1,power))
  if (power-2-out<(cap*0.5)) or (power-(width[c+1])*(height[c+1])-2-out- 
  width[c+1]<(cap*0.5)):
         power=cap
         print("Charging...")
  enter+=width[c]
```

Comment: What is your desired functionality when `c==n`?
Your current code won't necessarily lead to any errors - it depends on the number of items in the `width` and `height` lists

Comment: `for c in range(n-1)`?

Comment: When possible, reframe your problem so that you are considering the *previous* element instead of the next one. You won't even need the index in that case; you just remember the last value you saw. Not sure this is possible here, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a try/except block:

```py
for c in range (n):
  out=enter+width[c]
  if power==cap:
    power-=(width[c])*(height[c])*2+2+enter
  elif power<cap:
     power-=(width[c])*(height[c])*2
  print("Field {:d}: completed. Battery: {:d}.".format(c+1,power))
  try:
    if (power-2-out<(cap*0.5)) or (power-(width[c+1])*(height[c+1])-2-out-width[c+1]<(cap*0.5)):
      power=cap
      print("Charging...")
  except IndexError:
    print("error message here")
  enter+=width[c]
```

However, you probably want to figure out a different method.

Comment: Thanks, I did look into the try/except method, but I didn't realize except IndexError could be done. Thanks again.

Comment: @EdwardLeung if this solved your problem please check the grey/green checkmark to the left of this answer so that everyone knows it's been solved.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario I'd say you don't need to go all the way to `n`.

Maybe you should change your for-loop to `for c in range(n-1):`

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are going to want to iterate through the whole range, then you can use a list comprehension to generate the range as a list, then iterate over that list:

```
n = 1234  # Some number
nums = [x for x in range(n)]  # List comprehension generates a full list for the given range

for i, c in enumerate(nums):
    nums[i + 1]  # Access is valid, as long as index is within bounds of list size
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting the condition in your code, only run the if command if it's not out of range.

```
for c in range(n):
  out=enter+width[c]
  if power==cap:
         power-=(width[c])*(height[c])*2+2+enter
  elif power<cap:
         power-=(width[c])*(height[c])*2
  try:
       print("Field {:d}: completed. Battery: {:d}.".format(c+1,power))
  except:
        print("out of range")
  if (power-2-out<(cap*0.5)) :
         power=cap
         print("Charging...")

  elif c + 1 <= len(n) - 1:
    if (power-(width[c+1])*(height[c+1])-2-out-width[c+1]<(cap*0.5)):
               power=cap
               print("Charging...")
  enter+=width[c]
```